# NameError in UsersController#create uninitialized constant UsersController::Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error -

```
NameError in UsersController#create

uninitialized constant UsersController::Users
```

I want to mail function in my app.
My code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def log_out
    reset_session 
    redirect_to registrations_login_path
  end

  def create    
    @user = Users.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

I follow http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Comment: It should be `User.new(params[:user])`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear - it says you try to refer to `Users` constant, which is uninitialized. You probably meant `User`, representing `ActiveRecord` class:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Comment: @AmitGhosh I did it in my answer. What exactly you don't understand? You made simple typo, that's all.

Comment: model name is always singular and you are using plural that’s why it gives error.